# How to display Arraylist of type String in a dialogue 

Tags: android

I have a Arraylist of String type. How can i display it on a dialogue to a user and him select the one.also the need is to highlight the earlier selection in the made by the user.
Some code example will be helpful. 
thanks

Comment: Have you tried spinner for it?

Comment: Thanks Jaydeep. No i haven't tried but can spinner be used to display a list of strings as dialogue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in ur onCreate

```
protected CharSequence[] Months = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May","June", "July", "August", "September","October","November","December" };
Button selected_month = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.button );
selected_month.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                       new AlertDialog.Builder( <Classname>.this )
                  .setTitle( "Months" )
                      .setSingleChoiceItems( Months, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(<Classname>.this, Months[which], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        })
        .setPositiveButton( "OK", new DialogButtonClickHandler() )
        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogButtonClickHandler() )
        .create();
});
```